# Distributivity formula

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

I am reading J. Neveu's "Mathematical foundations of the calculus of probability." There he presents what he calls a distributivity formula:

$$\bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcap_{i \in I_j} F_i^j=\bigcap_{\{i_j\} \in K}\bigcup_{j \in J} F_{i_j}^j$$ where $K=\Pi_{j\in J}I_j$ (the set of all sequences {$i_j, j \in J$}).

My question is regarding the notation. The LHS is quite clear to me. However, I'm now sure what are actually the members of K. Say $J=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and $I_j=\{1,2,\ldots\}$. What is actually $i_j$ here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the RHS, we are finding the intersection of $\bigcup \limits_{j \in J} F_{i_j}^j$. Here, the $i_j$ is the values for which we are intersecting; it says $\{i_j\} \in K$. If $J = \{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$, then $K = I_1 \times I_2 \times I_3 \times \cdots$

Comment: Can you give an example of a member of $K$?

Comment: The member of $K$ depend on $I_n$'s. Let's say $I_1 = I_2 = I_3 = \{0,1,2\}$. Then, a member of $K$ for $J = \{1, 2, 3\}$ could be $(0,1,2)$, since $0 \in I_1$, $1 \in I_2$ and $2 \in I_3$.